# Is it possible to transform a matched group when doing a find/replace?

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Consider the following list of words:

```
targetX
targetY
targetZ
targetColor
targetWidth
```

I want to remove the "target" prefix, while maintaining the naming convention. This means that the first character after the prefix needs to be downcased:

```
x
y
z
color
width
```

So far I can match the text that I want and group the characters accordingly:

```
Find:    "target[A-Z]"
Replace: ???
```

But I don't know what I can do for the replace. Is there a regex substitution function that can do this in Visual Studio, or an alternative editor?

Comment: No, it is not possible, but you can do that in Notepad++ or SublimeText. Just use `\btarget([A-Z])` and replace with `\l$1`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - This is great! Exactly what I need! If you make it an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio S&R tool does not support upper-/lowercasing operators in the replacement part. The work around is to use Notepad++ or SublimeText with

Find: `\btarget([A-Z])`

Replace with: `\l$1`

Here, `\btarget` will match a word starting with `target` and `([A-Z])` will match and capture an uppercase ASCII letter into Group 1 that will later refernce with a `$1` backreference and turn it lowercase with `\l` operator.